# ubuntu 16.04 LTS login loop after updating driver nvidia-396

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, nvidia

I have an issue on login to my computer when nvidia-396 is installed. It returns to login screen after giving error message pop up. When I remove the nvidia* and restart lightdm it works fine.

Could you please help me fixing this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix by fully removing nvidia drivers with bumblebee.

```
sudo apt purge nvidia* bumblebee
```

And reinstalling

```
sudo apt install nvidia-396
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue with this driver.
my system is:

> Nvidia gtx 1060 (6gb)
>   AMD Fx 8350
>   ASUS motherboard

I was using the 390 driver ( 394.48 ), then upgraded to 396 and got this 'lightdm<->nvidia driver' problem.

It seems that mostly users are getting this bug too.

Unfortunately there's no solution yet, the nvidia-396 driver is still in ***beta*** according to [Nvidia drivers page](https://www.geforce.com/drivers). Just purge the 396 driver and switch back to an older version, then everything should work fine.

If not, see this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762831/ubuntu-16-stuck-in-login-loop-after-installing-nvidia-364-drivers) and this [Nvidia topic](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/969433) (only step 2, 4 and 5 are necessary for you, but yet the whole tutorial may become usefull) , it helped me to get the drivers working again after i messed up badly some files and packages.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did, no login screen after upgrading the Nvidia driver, it works for me.

login with console Ctrl+Alt+F1

1. login as root and remove the read-only file system by mounting `mount -o remount,rw /`
2. stop lightdm , `/ete/init.d/lightdm stop`. (if this is in inactive(dead) just copy backup xorg.conf.new file in your root directory and copy file to `/ete/X11/xorg.conf` and reboot)
3. then remove old nvidia Drivers, `apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
4. add the driver repository `add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
5. `apt-get update`
6. `apt-get install nvidia-387`
7. `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`
8. start lightdm `/etc/init.d/lightdb start`. or `reboot`.(Finished)

Answer (score 0):

1. Problem description
   Nvidia-396, which you have installed intently or unawarely auto-installed by other related package, such as swig, can not properly used in ubuntu 16.04.
2. Solution
   The best way to solve the problem would be ever find the miss-operation firstly. To do this, firstly, you need to check your command history by :

   vi ~/.bash_history

and then search "sudo" keywords which indicate essential command, and find suspects. In my case, it is

sudo install swig

Finally, revert it by :

sudo apt-get purge swig

CAUTION : PLEASE NEVER DO

sudo apt-get upgrade

It will install newest package of your whole system which will include nivida-396

Answer (score 0):

For me I just deleted the .Xauthority and two more of them having different suffixes from my home folder and it was working again fine!

Comment: Not 100% sure the OP will read this. But maybe you clarify your answer... It's a bit obscure to me what is to be deleted...

Comment: @LéopoldHoudin Sure. Let me try to be more clear. There will be files named .Xauthority, .Xauthority-i, .Xauthority-c etc in the home folder of linux(usually in `/home/{username}`). I deleted them and rebooted and it worked.